# Date filter using URL to API Rest - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, api, codeigniter

I want to display all my orders in a date interval, that was sent at URL : localhost/ws/v1/orders/2019-01-01/2019-01-31

But always my result is my first order, no matter what date i insert. If i type a URL without 2 dates, don't return nothing.

Controller

```
public function getOrders_get() {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    // Load Authorization Token Library
    $this->load->library('Authorization_Token');

    $fromDate =  $this->uri->segment(3);
    $toDate =  $this->uri->segment(4);

    /**
     * User Token Validation
     */
    $is_valid_token = $this->authorization_token->validateToken();

    if (!empty($is_valid_token) AND $is_valid_token['status'] === TRUE)
    {
      if (empty($id)){
          $data = $this->db->get_where("`ga845_pedidos_view` WHERE `data` BETWEEN date('$fromDate') AND date('$toDate')")->row_array();
      }else{
          $data = $this->db->get_where("ga845_pedidos_view", ['id' => $id])->row_array();
      }

      $this->response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);

    } else {
        $this->response(['status' => FALSE, 'message' => $is_valid_token['message'] ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Return:

```
 "id": "160",
  "data": "2017-01-25 12:33:24",
  "status": "3",
  ...
```

Comment: Just check what query is being built and debug your SQL query.
Get your last query by `$this->db->last_query()` and share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **solve** this that way.

My URL: localhost/ws/v1/2019-01-01/2019-01-10
1st - localhost ; 2nd - ws ; 3rt - v1 ; 4th - 2019-01-01 ; 5th - 2019-01-10

```
$fromDate =  $this->uri->segment(4); // 4 step of URL
$toDate =  $this->uri->segment(5);   // 5 step of URL

$this->db->where('order_date >=', $fromDate);
$this->db->where('order_date <=', $toDate);
$data = $this->db->get("order_table")->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert date in strtotime() and check like

```
        $from = strtotime($fromDate);
        $to = strtotime(toDate);
```

and Your query is

```
     BETWEEN {$from} AND {$to}
```